# Best way to mix and match components in a python app

Tags: python, architecture, composition

I have a component that uses a simple pub/sub module I wrote as a message queue. I would like to try out other implementations like RabbitMQ. However, I want to make this backend change configurable so I can switch between my implementation and 3rd party modules for cleanliness and testing.

The obvious answer seems to be to:

1. Read a config file
2. Create a modifiable settings object/dict
3. Modify the target component to lazily load the specified implementation.

something like :

```
# component.py
from test.queues import Queue

class Component:

  def __init__(self, Queue=Queue):
      self.queue = Queue()

  def publish(self, message):
      self.queue.publish(message)

# queues.py
import test.settings as settings

def Queue(*args, **kwargs):
  klass = settings.get('queue')
  return klass(*args, **kwargs)
```

Not sure if the init should take in the Queue class, I figure it would help in easily specifying the queue used while testing.

Another thought I had was something like http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html though that seems like it would get messy. Upside would be that I wouldn't have to modify the code to support swapping component.

Any other ideas or anecdotes would be appreciated.

EDIT: Fixed indent.

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code.

Answer (score 2):

One thing I've done before is to create a common class that each specific implementation inherits from. Then there's a spec that can easily be followed, and each implementation can avoid repeating certain code they'll all share.

This is a bad example, but you can see how you could make the saver object use any of the classes specified and the rest of your code wouldn't care.

```
class SaverTemplate(object):
    def __init__(self, name, obj):
        self.name = name
        self.obj = obj

    def save(self):
        raise NotImplementedError


import json
class JsonSaver(SaverTemplate):
    def save(self):
        file = open(self.name + '.json', 'wb')
        json.dump(self.object, file)
        file.close()

import cPickle
class PickleSaver(SaverTemplate):
    def save(self):
        file = open(self.name + '.pickle', 'wb')
        cPickle.dump(self.object, file, protocol=cPickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
        file.close()

import yaml
class PickleSaver(SaverTemplate):
    def save(self):
        file = open(self.name + '.yaml', 'wb')
        yaml.dump(self.object, file)
        file.close()


saver = PickleSaver('whatever', foo)
saver.save()
```

Comment: I get what you're saying. What if you want to add the Saver to a component and swap out between Json, PickleSaver, and YamlSaver?